# Visual Programming Language Control

Tags: c#, .net, simulation, visual-programming

Is there a .NET based (WinForm or WPF) control that allows simple visual programming (assignments, boolean expressions, and math expressions)?  Something like [Microsoft VPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb483088.aspx), only embeddable and supported.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

There is a new open source library out there: TUM.CMS.VPLControl. Get it [here](https://github.com/tumcms/TUM.CMS.VPLControl).

[image]