# Definition of a visual programming language (like BPMN and LabView)

Tags: architecture, definition, labview, bpmn

I am looking for an exact definition for visual programming languages (VPL) which includes also a classification. I am of course aware of the [Wiki page on VPLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_programming_language) but what I am after is a definition which includes classification by purpose, ideally with a reference to a publication.

Somehow (not perfectly) related websites and posts:

- [Visual Programming Language Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269439/visual-programming-language-control)
- [Read LabView program without LabView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37109228/read-labview-program-without-labview)
- [Advantages and disadvantages of BPMN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776778/)
- [Lecture on VPNs](http://www.mathematik.uni-marburg.de/~swt/ws12/vs/files/FolienVS130205.pdf) (unfortunately in German)

Comment: Since you seem to be able to read German, what about https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visuelle_Programmiersprache ? To me it looks like this is a rather detailed description of what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably Google's [Blockly](https://developers.google.com/blockly/) is what you are looking for. They provide very helpful publications regarding their product and VPL. From their [publication](https://developers.google.com/blockly/publications/papers/TipsForCreatingABlockLanguage.pdf)

> A Visual Programming Language (VPL) is a programming
>   language that allows a user to create programs primarily
>   through graphical manipulation. Some common interaction
>   models in VPLs are:
>
> - Dragging blocks around a screen (e.g. [Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/))
> - Using flow diagrams, state diagrams, and other component wirings (e.g. [Pure Data](https://puredata.info/))
> - Using icons or non-text representation (e.g. [Kodu](https://www.kodugamelab.com/))

Hope this helps.